# Convert UIImage into bytes

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, byte, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

I am getting UIImage using UIImagePickerController. How can i calculate number of bytes hold by that Image in kb/mb ?

Using that values I have to make logic that user cant add Images more than size of 1MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Convert the `UIImage` to a `NSData` object, which has the `length` property, which will give you its size in bytes. Then you can easily calculate the size in whatever unit you need.

So for example:

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some.png"];
    NSData *dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
    int bytes = [dataObj length];
    //convert into whatever unit you need
```

Comment: You can also use `UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)`

Comment: Of course - I don't know which one he prefers but that's a good point. +1

Comment: @AvtarGuleria - when you do this, you are encoding and then decoding the image, and your resulting data can grow to twice as large as the original file!  If you use the ALAssetsLibrary class you can get the original NSData, which will be the size you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can get image size from following delegate method of UIImagePickerController

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
     if([UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) length]> MAX_SIZE)
     {
         //Code here
     }
}
```

Here, You can see, I have converted Image into data, and [data length] can give bytes length.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than stopping the user from uploading images of more than 1MB, you would serve your user better by scaling and compressing the image to save space I suspect. However to answer your question, one way would simply be;

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info {


NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // Or UIImageJPEGRepresentation 
long sizeInBytes = [imageData length];

// do stuff

}
```